# How to checkout payment for laravel framework

Tags: laravel

my code is below,basically integrate will completed .but j query function all is not working ,i dont know what is a problem there,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/abserve/js/jquery.creditCardValidator.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function cardFormValidate(){
var cardValid = 0;

//Card validation
$('#card_number').validateCreditCard(function(result) {
    var cardType = (result.card_type == null)?'':result.card_type.name;
    if(cardType == 'Visa'){
        var backPosition = result.valid?'2px -163px, 260px -87px':'2px -163px, 260px -61px';
    }else if(cardType == 'MasterCard'){
        var backPosition = result.valid?'2px -247px, 260px -87px':'2px -247px, 260px -61px';
    }else if(cardType == 'Maestro'){
        var backPosition = result.valid?'2px -289px, 260px -87px':'2px -289px, 260px -61px';
    }else if(cardType == 'Discover'){
        var backPosition = result.valid?'2px -331px, 260px -87px':'2px -331px, 260px -61px';
    }else if(cardType == 'Amex'){
        var backPosition = result.valid?'2px -121px, 260px -87px':'2px -121px, 260px -61px';
    }else{
        var backPosition = result.valid?'2px -121px, 260px -87px':'2px -121px, 260px -61px';
    }
    $('#card_number').css("background-position", backPosition);
    if(result.valid){
        $("#card_type").val(cardType);
        $("#card_number").removeClass('required');
        cardValid = 1;
    }else{
        $("#card_type").val('');
        $("#card_number").addClass('required');
        cardValid = 0;
    }
});

//Form validation
var cardName = $("#name_on_card").val();
var expMonth = $("#expiry_month").val();
var expYear = $("#expiry_year").val();
var cvv = $("#cvv").val();
var regName = /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i;
var regMonth = /^01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12$/;
var regYear = /^2016|2017|2018|2019|2020|2021|2022|2023|2024|2025|2026|2027|2028|2029|2030|2031$/;
var regCVV = /^[0-9]{3,3}$/;
if (cardValid == 0) {
    $("#card_number").addClass('required');
    $("#card_number").focus();
    return false;
}else if (!regMonth.test(expMonth)) {
    $("#card_number").removeClass('required');
    $("#expiry_month").addClass('required');
    $("#expiry_month").focus();
    return false;
}else if (!regYear.test(expYear)) {
    $("#card_number").removeClass('required');
    $("#expiry_month").removeClass('required');
    $("#expiry_year").addClass('required');
    $("#expiry_year").focus();
    return false;
}else if (!regCVV.test(cvv)) {
    $("#card_number").removeClass('required');
    $("#expiry_month").removeClass('required');
    $("#expiry_year").removeClass('required');
    $("#cvv").addClass('required');
    $("#cvv").focus();
    return false;
}else if (!regName.test(cardName)) {
    $("#card_number").removeClass('required');
    $("#expiry_month").removeClass('required');
    $("#expiry_year").removeClass('required');
    $("#cvv").removeClass('required');
    $("#name_on_card").addClass('required');
    $("#name_on_card").focus();
    return false;
}else{
    $("#card_number").removeClass('required');
    $("#expiry_month").removeClass('required');
    $("#expiry_year").removeClass('required');
    $("#cvv").removeClass('required');
    $("#name_on_card").removeClass('required');
    $('#cardSubmitBtn').prop('', false);  
    return true;
}
}


    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Demo card numbers
        $('.card-payment .numbers li').wrapInner('<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.card-payment .numbers').slideUp(100);
            cardFormValidate()
            return $('#card_number').val($(this).text()).trigger('input');
        });
        $('body').click(function() {
            return $('.card-payment .numbers').slideUp(100);
        });
        $('#sample-numbers-trigger').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return $('.card-payment .numbers').slideDown(100);
        });

        //Card form validation on input fields
        $('#paymentForm input[type=text]').on('keyup',function(){
            cardFormValidate();
        });

        //Submit card form
        $("#cardSubmitBtn").on('click',function(){
            if (cardFormValidate()) {
                var formData = $('#paymentForm').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: base_url+'/pixelz/card',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data:formData,
                    beforeSend: function(){  
                        $("#cardSubmitBtn").val('Processing....');
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        if (data.status == 1) {
                            $('#paymentSection').slideUp('slow');
                            $('#orderInfo').slideDown('slow');
                            $('#orderInfo').html('<p>Order <span>#'+data.orderID+'</span> has been submitted successfully.</p>');
                        }else{
                            $('#paymentSection').slideUp('slow');
                            $('#orderInfo').slideDown('slow');
                            $('#orderInfo').html('<p>Wrong card details given, please try again.</p>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="card-payment" style="position:relative;margin-top: 64px; left: 500px">
<h3 id="try-it">{{ Lang::get('2checkout payment') }}</h3>

 <div id="paymentSection">
  <form action="<?php echo url();?>/pay_via_paypal" id="paymentForm" method="post">

       <ul>
              <input type="hidden" name="card_type" id="card_type" value=""/>
              <li>
                  <label for="card_number">Card number (<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="sample-numbers-trigger">try one of these</a>)</label>
                  <div class="numbers" style="display: none;">
                      <p>Try some of these numbers:</p>

                      <ul class="list">
                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">4000 0000 0000 0002</a></li>
                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">5018 0000 0009</a></li>
                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">5100 0000 0000 0008</a></li>
                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">6011 0000 0000 0004</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456" id="card_number" name="card_number" class="">

                  <small class="help">This demo supports Visa, American Express, Maestro, MasterCard and Discover.</small>              </li>

              <li class="vertical">
                  <ul>
                      <li>
                          <label for="expiry_month">Expiry month</label>
                          <input type="text" placeholder="MM" maxlength="5" id="expiry_month" name="expiry_month">
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <label for="expiry_year">Expiry year</label>
                          <input type="text" placeholder="YYYY" maxlength="5" id="expiry_year" name="expiry_year">
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
                          <input type="text" placeholder="123" maxlength="3" id="cvv" name="cvv">
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <label for="name_on_card">Name on card</label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Codex World" id="name_on_card" name="name_on_card">
              </li>
              <li><input type="button" name="card_submit" id="cardSubmitBtn" value="Proceed" class="payment-btn"></li>
              <p style="color:#EA0075;">Note that: This demo will working with PayPal sandbox accounts.</p>
          </ul>
      </form>
  </div>
    <div id="orderInfo" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: read about How to ask Question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "Here is some stuff. It doesn't work. Why?" You are going to have to meet people halfway, narrow down your code to *specifically* what is not working, follow up error messages, and tell us a little more what "it doesn't work" means.